# azure Visual Studio Professional with MSDN offer

Tags: azure

I just activated my Visual Studio Professional with MSDN and it is telling me now that I have $200 to spend,
my question is: 
is this will take $200 from my credit card after the month is over, or this is an offer, and can I use and rely on windows azure using these $200 monthly or this is a limited time offer and will expire after few months? if it is limited so I can't transfer my live websites on azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information provided by @hhaggan is off a bit. If you read [this page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0045p) containing the benefits details for Visual Studio Professional with MSDN, you'll see the following:

> For the first month after activation of your benefit, you receive $200
>   of Windows Azure credits. After the first month, you receive $50 of
>   Windows Azure credits every month

So it's not a continued $200 monthly.

I couldn't tell if you're intending to use your MSDN Azure benefit for dev/test or production. These Azure credits are for dev/test purposes, and not for production, as documented on the abovementioned web page. Under **Use Rights**:

> Windows Azure MSDN benefit is intended for development and test
>   purposes. We reserve the right to suspend any instance (VM or cloud
>   service) that runs continuously for more than 120 hours or if we
>   determine that the instance is being used for production. Production
>   workloads must be run on regular subscriptions.

Comment: Understood it now very well, thank you very much for these info.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN Subscriber will have free of charge Windows Azure account that worth 200$ per month.  it all depends on your usage, you can use all the resources in one day, one week or even with the best consumption use your resources for the whole month, however if you exceed the limit it will not charge you.  the Credit card used here is mainly to provide a guaranteed identity.  the offer should be for the whole year of subscription.

I hope this helps you let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: So what I have now after activating this offer is $200 per month, and I will have new $200 every new month, and can spend them correct?, another question, do you know after how many months this offer will expire?

Comment: yes this correct you will have a monthly 200 $ of resources to spend, this offer I think it will endure for the duration of the MSDN subscription account which is a year as far as I remember